# Why do I need to use .d to access data returned by jQuery AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, serialization

I've put together some jQuery AJAX code using some tutorials I found on the internet.  I'm new to jQuery and want to learn how to do things betters.  I have a coworker who put together a beautiful web application using a lot of jQuery.

The thing I'm most confused about here is: why is it necessary to use the ".d" when referring to the response of my web method and what does it stand for?

```
    // ASP.net C# code
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string hello()
    {
        return ("howdy");
    }

// Javascript code
function testMethod() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ViewNamesAndNumbers.aspx/hello",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);   // This doesn't display the response.
            alert(msg.d); // This displays the response.
        } // end success:
    }) // end $.ajax
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was added in ASP.NET 3.5’s version of ASP.NET AJAX to prevent you from being vulnerable to this exploit: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

(Answer sourced from http://encosia.com/2009/06/29/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/)

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft does this to protect you from a security exploit.  See the bottom of [This Page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Using%20JSON%20Syntax%20with%20Ajax.ashx) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

I guess `alert(msg)` displays "[object Object]" ?

If so it's because the object which is parsed through `window.JSON` (which happens under the hood when specifying `json` as dataType) does really look:

```
object = {
    d:   "some data"
}
```

Check what you are generating in ViewNamesAndNumbers.aspx/hello