# i am trying to get city list by calling webservice using the code below

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services, ksoap2

Here is the exception I am getting

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT [{"Id":"57","Tit...@1:275 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b629f48)

with the following code

```
public String SuggestCity  (String CityName)  {
    SoapObject soapObject=new       SoapObject(Wsdl_Target_NameSpace,Operation_Name);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo=new PropertyInfo();
    propertyInfo.setName("tryValue");
    propertyInfo.setValue(CityName);
    propertyInfo.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfo);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope serializationEnvelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    serializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
    serializationEnvelope.dotNet=true;
    String response=null;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Soap_Adrress);
   //androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    androidHttpTransport.debug=true;


    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(Soap_Action, serializationEnvelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) serializationEnvelope.getResponse();
        response=result.toString();
        Log.d("asdf",result.toString());
        //response=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
    }
   catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Haha",e.toString());
    }
    return response;

}
```

any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to parse the result, which is JSON, to XML. Is the service you are calling a WCF service?

Comment: This is the url , i am using http://test.maheshwari.org/services/testwebservice.asmx ,How to remove this exception??  @RichardMosselveld

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON response from a 3.5 asmx web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563641/how-to-get-json-response-from-a-3-5-asmx-web-service)

Comment: Thanx @Richard Mosselveld ,Any way of doing it through ksoap2 ???

Comment: No, unfortunatelly do i not have that much ksoap2 knowlegde. Try searching the combination json/ksoap2

Comment: Okay thanx  :) @RichardMosselveld