# Use Json.NET as default json serializer in C# Website

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a `WebMethod` like this one:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Event> getEvents()
{
    var db = new DbContext();
    var events = from x in db.Event select x;

    return events.ToList();
}
```

By default it use `JsonSerializer` from .NET i want to use Json.Net as default serializer it is possible?

It isn't a WFC project, it's a Website project in Visual Studio.

Comment: it's not WCF project

Comment: Does this answer help?  [How to get JSON response from a 3.5 asmx web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563641/how-to-get-json-response-from-a-3-5-asmx-web-service/19564022#19564022).  You would replace `Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(data));` with `Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(events));`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Json.net already then you just need to ensure you have the `using` statement and you can just return the json string:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(events.ToList());
return json;
```

This should do it.

Comment: this not work. because the default serializer serialize the string returned from `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Comment: Try removing the line `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`

Comment: your return type should be `string`.

Comment: I have to remove `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` try but it serialize to XML

Comment: ah - you must be requesting as XML - you'll need to specify json in the request. you'll need `Content-Type:application/json` in the header

Comment: Yeah i know, but without `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` it alway return XML, when the `Content-Type` setted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113134/discussion-between-rick-and-cronos).

Comment: You can prevent the xml serialization with: [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml, UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]