# ajax and json functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hello evry body i need a small help from your side explaning in bit detail about the below code which i couldnt able to understand as i was bit new to the this Jquery...

hope i can get a proper response from your side and explanation from scratch about the functionality from the level of wrapper classes which is embedded in this jquery
 function BindProfileDetails() {

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "NewMyprofile.aspx/Populate_details",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d) {
                        $(data.d).each(function (index, item) {

                            if (index == 0) {

                                $("#txtfname").val(item.fname);
                                $('#txtLname ').val(item.lname);
                                $('#Txtsurname').val(item.surname);
                                $('#txtmob').val(item.mob);
                                $('#Txtphone').val(item.phone);
                                $('#Txtextension').val(item.ext);
                                $('#ddlyop').val(item.yop);
                                $('#txtEmailId').val(item.email);
                                $('#txtaddress ').val(item.address);
                                $('#txtadd1').val(item.addrclg);
                                $('#txtqual').val(item.quali);
                                $('#Txtuniv').val(item.univ);

                                if (item.sex == "True") {
                                    $("#rdbmale").attr("checked", false);
                                    $("#rdfemale").attr("checked", true);
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#rdbmale").attr("checked", true);
                                    $("#rdfemale").attr("checked", false);
                                }

                                if (item.maritialst == "True") {
                                    $("#rdmarry").attr("checked", false);
                                    $("#Rdsingle").attr("checked", true);
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#rdmarry").attr("checked", true);
                                    $("#Rdsingle").attr("checked", false);
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

            });

        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question ? What exactly do you not understand ?

Comment: in .ajax type,datatype, and especially (data.d).each function

Comment: Better go through docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: what value will be passed in function (data) which is written in success:

Comment: thanks for ur link Raju Rudru

Comment: i didnt declared data there then how can it be accessed in the function pls any one can clarify my doubt rather than down voting my question

Comment: `data` will be the response you get from ajax call.

Comment: how can we understand the working of data.d here @little suzy

Comment: That will depend on the response. Who wrote the code? Tell him/her to explain

Comment: can we say the return value 'data' from ajax call is a class and 'd' here as a wrapper class ? is my understanding right? whts the need to use .d here is it just for security even though i referred the working of .d i couldnt able to get it

Comment: is that my post that worst everyone really down voting my post should i need to delete it...

Comment: Thank u all for your kind support in understanding this concept to an extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to explain -

1. 'ajax' stands for Async. Javascript And XML. You can make XML HTTP Requests using ajax.
2. type - Describes the type of your request (POST/GET/PUT/DELETE) - you need to specify your request type in this section. Know more on the request types [here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html).
3. url - defines the url to which you want to make the request.
4. dataType and contentType - preferred data type and content type for the communication.
5. success - program control will come into it if the communication succeeds. You can have the response as the function parameter (For your case, this is 'data').
6. data.d - The response is wrapped with a key 'd'. So, you will get the actual response in 'data.d', not in data. This is customizable. Know more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927851/why-do-i-need-to-use-d-to-access-data-returned-by-jquery-ajax).
7. $(data.d).each(function (index, item) - Does a simple 'foreach' loop with your data.d object. So, it will execute for each item present in your data.d object. The parameters - 'item' holds the actual item (current item) and 'index' holds the loop-index. As per your code, this is setting values to some fields using the data item.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: 6th point is really useful to me..and thats my doubt thank u very much subha ji for ur kind help..