# Formatting a URL for AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a jQuery program that calls a web service via AJAX.  Please see the code in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656092/jquery-ajax-not-returning-value) I asked earlier:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function(){
            alert('Test');
            $('#div1 h2').text('Hi I am replace');
            var divToBeWorkedOn = "#div1";
            var n1 = 1;
            var n2 = 2;
            var webMethod = "Service1.svc/getNumber";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: webMethod,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(val(result));
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(e.responseText);
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

I discovered after reading the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error) that you *cannot* make cross domain calls using jQuery without applying a setting, which I have now done.

How do you specify the AJAX URL. The following both error:

```
http://mypc/Service1.svc/HelloWorld
http://mypc/Service1.svc\HelloWorld
```

`HelloWorld` is the function that I want to call contained in the web service.  `HelloWorld` returns an `integer`.

Comment: "*The following both error*" What is the error being thrown?

Comment: I suppose that this link could be useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221429/how-can-i-produce-jsonp-from-an-asp-net-web-service-for-cross-domain-calls

Comment: @chf, is this the same for WCF?

Comment: I googled for you: http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery