# Null value is always sending from AJAX to controller class whenever a value is selected from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I want to fetch data from the database whenever the user selects a value from drop down. For these purpose I have written a block for code, in which a JavaScript function is call whenever a user selects a value from drop down and passes that value to the controller through ajax. Below is the snapshot of the code.

**cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Code", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "fetchData(this.value)" })
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    function fetchData(Code) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@(Url.Action("fetchCode", "ChargesSetup"))',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'Code':'" + Code + "'}",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log("E");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

> NOTE: I have tried my format for passing data to controller, the value
>   of code inside JavaScript is correct as 'A'. But in controller class
>   is show as `@p__linq__0`. when I hard code the value of code the controller
>   work fine.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult fetchData(string Code)
{
      IQueryable chargestable = from p in db.chargestable where (p.Code == Code) select p;
      return Json(chargestable , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In JavaScript the value of drop down is exactly same what we want:

[image: Value of drop down in JS]

but after AJAX call, in controller the value of drop down is change to some thing like `@p__linq__0`

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[area] AS [area]
FROM [dbo].[chargestable] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Code] = @p__linq__0}
```

What is problem with my code? How can I resolve this as I need to get the buffer of `chargestable` whenever drop down value is selected.

By changing return statement makes no effect because the value of parameter is not set, its always null.

```
return Json(chargestable.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[image: Value of Parameter]

Comment: What you are seeing in that last code block is the SQL generated by your LINQ statement. I think what you want is to do `return Json(chargestable.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. That will execute the `IQueryable` and return the data.

Comment: return null object. Object
AsyncState
:
null
CreationOptions
:
0
Exception
:
null
Id
:
107
IsCanceled
:
false
IsCompleted
:
true
IsFaulted
:
false
Result
:
Array(0)
length
:
0
__proto__
:
Array(0)
Status
:
5
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Well, sure, it's not finding any matches, so it's null. I think the whole `@p__linq__0` thing is a red herring. To get the parameter, you might try adding `[FromBody]` in your controller method: `fetchData([FromBody] string Code)`.

Comment: You should also see if `Code` is defined in your JavaScript function as well...

Comment: First of all, an entry is found against the select value in the table. secondly the code variable is also defining in JavaScript and a value of its also output and attach in above question description.

Comment: Okay... that's not at all clear in the question. If the picture attached there is indeed the value of the JavaScript `Code` variable, it shows an empty array. Your controller function takes a string. Of what type is the `Code` column on your `chargestable` database table?

Comment: it's varchar. The first line on picture show the value of Code in JS and second line empty array, is the result comes from controller class. console.log(result) line in success: function  (JavaScript).

Comment: Try console.log(result.d); in you success. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927851/why-do-i-need-to-use-d-to-access-data-returned-by-jquery-ajax