# Unwanted Extra Array Enclosed In JSON API response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, rest

I have a JSON response that I want to send after processing the input and I convert a Datatable into JSON and send it but it is enclosed within a new array `'d' : []`

This is my API JSON input:

```json
{
    "region_id": "ID-10",
    "document_number": "10-80/81-BIN-00005",
    "industry_no": "10-CNO-0001",
    "posting_date": "14-07-2080",
    "customer_number": "10-CNO-0001",
    "payment_for": [
      {"BillType": "पानी महशुल"}
 ] }
```

and this is my API response.
I am not sure why the `"d"` is present:

```json
{  
    "d": "[{\"CustomerNo\":\"10-CNO-0001\",\"PostingDate\":\"2023-10-31T00:00:00\",\"DocumentNo\":\"10-80/81-BIN-00005\",\"BillType\":\"5\",\"Description\":\"पानी महशुल\",\"Quantity\":0.00000,\"Rate\":0.00000,\"Amount\":1000.00,\"RegionID\":\"ID-10\",\"ExpenseID\":\"0\",\"ActivityID\":\"0\",\"SubActivityID\":\"0\",\"Dimension5ID\":\"\",\"FineAmount\":0.00,\"DiscountAmount\":-40.00,\"IsPaid\":false,\"priority\":\"2\",\"billType\":\"5\"}]"  
}
```

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[AllowAnonymous]
public string InitialFetch(string region_id, string document_number, string industry_no, string posting_date, string customer_number, List<PaymentForItem> payment_for)
{
    try
    {
        // Create a dictionary to represent the processed data
        var extractedData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "region_id", region_id },
            { "document_number", document_number },
            { "industry_no", industry_no },
            { "posting_date", posting_date },
            { "customer_number", customer_number },
            { "payment_for", payment_for.Select(item => new Dictionary<string, object> { { "BillType", item.BillType } }).ToList() }
        };

        // Call the original GetReceivableByBillTypeFromLaravel method a datatable is extracted 
        DataTable receiptData = GetReceivableByBillTypeFromLaravel(extractedData);

        // Serialize the response to JSON
        string jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(receiptData);

        return jsonResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions and return an error response
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = "Error: " + ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Above is my code for processing the API.

I have another set of method `GetReceivableByBillTypeFromLaravel` that actually formulates the data table if need be I will post that too.

Comment: What is `DataTable` and why do you expect it to serialize into anything different than your actual response?

Comment: A datatable has automatic serialization. If you want something else you need to do it yourself, by building a `IEnumerable<JObject>` or similar.

Comment: What .NET version + server tooling are you using?  Are you using the old [ASP.NET AJAX Web Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services)?  If so, this may be a duplicate of [What does .d in JSON mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/830112) and [Why do ASP.NET JSON web services return the result in 'd'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6588589) and [Why do I need to use .d to access data returned by jQuery AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3927851).